# To count the word frequency in multiple documents python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have a list of the addresses of multiple text files in a dictionary 'd':

```
'd:/individual-articles/9.txt', 'd:/individual-articles/11.txt', 'd:/individual-articles/12.txt',...
```

and so on...

Now, I need to read each file in the dictionary and keep a list of the word occurrences of each  and every word that occurs in the entire dictionary.

My output should be of the form:

```
the-500

a-78

in-56
```

and so on..

where 500 is the number of times the word "the" occurs in all the files in the dictionary..and so on..

I need to do this for all the words.

I am a python newbie..plz help!

My code below doesn't work,it shows no output!There must be a mistake in my logic, please rectify!!

```
import collections
import itertools
import os
from glob import glob
from collections import Counter




folderpaths='d:/individual-articles'
counter=Counter()


filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpaths,'*.txt'))




folderpath='d:/individual-articles/'
# i am creating my dictionary here, can be ignored
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('topics.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       value, *keys = line.strip().split('~')
        for key in filter(None, keys):
            if key=='earn':
               d[key].append(folderpath+value+".txt")

   for key, value in d.items() :
        print(value)


word_count_dict={}

for file in d.values():
    with open(file,"r") as f:
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', f.read().lower())
        counter = counter + Counter(words)
        for word in words:
            word_count_dict[word].append(counter)              


for word, counts in word_count_dict.values():
    print(word, counts)
```

Comment: +1 for actually trying and posting code before asking :) These days most users expect SO folks to work as 0$ freelancers.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from the `Counter` collection that you use:

```
from glob import glob
from collections import Counter
import re

folderpaths = 'd:/individual-articles'
counter = Counter()

filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpaths,'*.txt'))
for file in filepaths:
    with open(file) as f:
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', f.read().lower())
        counter = counter + Counter(words)
print counter
```

Comment: yes, but i must read only from the files that are present in dictionary "d"..how can i do that?

Comment: @thg435 could you please tell me how to go over the files in the dictionary?

Comment: I was on a hot point, so I couldn't answer you before. From what I see in your post, you succeeded, right ?

Comment: yes i did! thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

Your code *should* give you an error in this line:

```
word_count_dict[word][file]+= 1
```

Because your `word_count_dict` is empty, so when you do `word_count_dict[word][file]` you should get a key error, because `word_count_dict[word]` doesn't exist, so you can do `[file]` on it.

And I found another error:

```
while file in d.items():
```

This would make file a tuple. But then you do `f = open(file,"r")`, so you assume `file` is a string. This would also raise an error.

This means that none of these lines are ever executed. That in turn means that **either `while file in d.items():` is empty or for `file in filepaths:` is empty.**

And to be honest I don't understand why you have both of them. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve there. You have generated a list of filenames to parse. You should just iterate over them. I also don't know why `d` is a dict. All you need is a list of all the files. You don't need to keep track of when key the file came from in the topics, list, do you?

Comment: yes i have edited my code for the 1st part, i donno how to go abt the second part,i.e, reading the files from dict..could u plz help!

Comment: @PokerFace: Well, I just told you three errors you have in your code, if you fix them, that will help.

Comment: yes, i am unable to fix the second error..how do i avoid making the file a string?

Comment: @PokerFace: Avoid? You want it to be a string, otherwise the open() will fail. Also, I would like to point out that I asked you a question that you haven't answered.

Comment: i am sorry i meant tuple..and yeah i want it to be in the dict, as the key values will change as i proceed later on..its important..

Comment: @PokerFace: Then use .values() instead of .items().

Comment: it doesn't work!and yes, you're right!while file in d.items(): makes it a tuple..could u suggest an alternative?

Comment: @PokerFace: I'm sorry, I've told you what to do, I can't help you further when you don't actually read my answers.