# Word frequency count based on two words using python

Tags: csv, python-2.7, count, frequency-analysis, word-frequency

There are many resources online that shows how to do a word count for single word 
like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173592/word-frequency-in-text-using-python-but-disregard-stop-words?rq=1)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919604/efficiently-calculate-word-frequency-in-a-string) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399535/to-count-the-word-frequency-in-multiple-documents-python) and others...
But I was not not able to find a concrete example for two words count frequency .

I have a csv file that has some strings in it.

```
FileList = "I love TV show makes me happy, I love also comedy show makes me feel like flying"
```

So I want the output to be like :

```
wordscount =  {"I love": 2, "show makes": 2, "makes me" : 2 }
```

Of course I will have to strip all the comma, interrogation points.... `{!, , ", ', ?, ., (,), [, ], ^, %, #, @, &, *, -, _, ;, /, \, |, }`

I will also remove some stop words which I found [here](http://www.textfixer.com/resources/common-english-words.php) just to get more concrete data from the text.

How can I achieve this results using python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> sentence = "I love TV show makes me happy, I love also comedy show makes me feel like flying"
>>> words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)
>>> two_words = [' '.join(ws) for ws in zip(words, words[1:])]
>>> wordscount = {w:f for w, f in Counter(two_words).most_common() if f > 1}
>>> wordscount
{'show makes': 2, 'makes me': 2, 'I love': 2}
```