# Given a text count occurrences of all two consecutive words

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, n-gram

**Input:**

```
Once upon a time a time this upon a
```

**Output:**

```
dictionary {
    'Once upon': 1,
       'upon a': 2,
       'a time': 2,
       'time a': 1,
    'time this': 1,
    'this upon': 1
}
```

**CODE:**

```
def countTuples(path):
    dic = dict()
    with codecs.open(path, 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            s = line.split()
            for i in range (0, len(s)-1):
                dic[str(s[i]) + ' ' + str(s[i+1])] += 1
    return dic
```

I am getting this error:

```
File "C:/Users/user/Anaconda3/hw2.py", line 100, in countTuples
    dic[str(s[i]) + ' ' + str(s[i+1])] += 1
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

If I remove the `+=` and just place `=1` everything works just fine, I guess the problem is when I try to access an entry to extract a value that doesn't exist yet ?

What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: Use a `Counter`...

Comment: A counter will iterate for every tuple over the file. I can't afford that, it will be n^2 in time complexity and I want to avoid that.
@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: not if you use `zip`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make your solution work. With a `defaultdict`, you specify the default type of the value of a key-value pair. This allows you to make an assignment like `+=1` to a key which has not been explicitly created, yet:

```
import codecs
from collections import defaultdict

def countTuples(path):
    dic = defaultdict(int)
    with codecs.open(path, 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            s = line.split()
            for i in range (0, len(s)-1):
                dic[str(s[i]) + ' ' + str(s[i+1])] += 1
    return dic

>>> {'Once upon': 1,
     'a time': 2,
     'this upon': 1,
     'time a': 1,
     'time this': 1,
     'upon a': 2})
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution that requires minimal changing of your code is to just use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

line = 'Once upon a time a time this upon a'

dic = defaultdict(int)

s = line.split()

for i in range(0, len(s)-1):
    dic[str(s[i]) + ' ' + str(s[i+1])] += 1
```

This produces:

```
dic

defaultdict(int,
            {'Once upon': 1,
             'a time': 2,
             'this upon': 1,
             'time a': 1,
             'time this': 1,
             'upon a': 2})
```

Your function then just becomes:

```
def countTuples(path):
    dic = defaultdict(int)
    with codecs.open(path, 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            s = line.split()
            for i in range (0, len(s)-1):
                dic[str(s[i]) + ' ' + str(s[i+1])] += 1
    return dic
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to make it that hard, simply use a `Counter` and use `zip` to feed bigrams to the counter, like:

```
from collections import Counter

def countTuples(path):
    dic = Counter()
    with codecs.open(path, 'r', 'utf-8') as f
        for line in f:
            s = line.split()
            dic.update('%s %s'%t for t in zip(s,s[1:]))
    return dic
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I've found so far is from [Word frequency count based on two words using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952894/word-frequency-count-based-on-two-words-using-python)

```
from collections import Counter
two_words = [' '.join(ws) for ws in zip(text, text[1:])]
dic = {w:f for w, f in Counter(two_words).most_common() if f>1}
```

One can modify the `if f>1` part to get the two consecutive words over a threshold.